# Extracting data from xml to a text file

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to extract the data from xml file and write it to a text file. I have a xml file and xsl file but I am not getting the output as expected.

XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <MessageStart>
        <Header>
                <College>University of Data</College>
                <State>AAA</State>
                <Country>BBB</Country>
        </Header>
        <Body>
            <Department>
                    <DeptNum>001</DeptNum>
                    <DeptName>Computers</DeptName>
                    <DeptTotal>100</DeptTotal>
            </Department>
            <Department>
                    <DeptNum>002</DeptNum>
                    <DeptName>IT</DeptName>
                    <DeptTotal>200</DeptTotal>
            </Department>
            <Department>
                    <DeptNum>003</DeptNum>
                    <DeptName>Civil</DeptName>
                    <DeptTotal>300</DeptTotal>
            </Department>   
        </Body>
    </MessageStart>
```

XSLT

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yesy" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="MessageStart">
                <xsl:value-of select="Header/College"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="Body/Department">
                 <xsl:value-of select="DeptNum"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                 <xsl:value-of select="DeptName"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                 <xsl:value-of select="DeptTotal"/>
                 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output

```
University of Data|AAA|BBB|001|Computers|100 
University of Data|AAA|BBB|002|IT|200
University of Data|AAA|BBB|003|Civil|300
```

Comment: This is my expected output:


    Expected Output:
    University of Data|001|Computers|100
    University of Data|002|IT|200
    University of Data|003|Civil|300

Comment: Please add this to your question and format it properly.

Comment: I tried adding it to the original post but no matter what I do , it still says not formatted properly. Hence added it in the comments

Comment: Does this work OK  for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/MessageStart">
    <xsl:variable name="college" select="Header/College"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="Body/Department">
         <xsl:value-of select="$college"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="DeptNum"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="DeptName"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="DeptTotal"/>
         <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you have multiple values in the header then use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/MessageStart">
    <xsl:variable name="header">
         <xsl:value-of select="Header/College"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="Header/State"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="Header/Country"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="Body/Department">
         <xsl:value-of select="$header"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="DeptNum"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="DeptName"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="DeptTotal"/>
         <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so if i have around 10 columns in my header and if I want all of them for every row, do I need to declare 10 variables?

Comment: You need only one variable that contains the entire text block that is shared by all rows (including the delimiters).

Comment: To be more precise, you don't *need* the variable at all. It just eliminates the extra work of walking up and down the tree for every value that needs to be fetched from the header.

Comment: so if I have address and college under my header as below:
<Header>
     <College> University of Data </College>
    <State>AAA</state>
   <Country>BBB</Country>
</Header>

How can I get all the 3 values for every row in my text file?

Comment: I think it would be better to update your question with a more relevant example.

Comment: I have updated my xml file:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <MessageStart>
     <Header>
       <College>University of Data</College>
                <State>AAA</State>
                <Country>BBB</Country>
     </Header>
     <Body>
      <Department>
        <DeptNum>001</DeptNum>
        <DeptName>Computers</DeptName>
        <DeptTotal>100</DeptTotal>
      </Department>
      <Department>
        <DeptNum>002</DeptNum>
        <DeptName>IT</DeptName>
        <DeptTotal>200</DeptTotal>
      </Department> 
     </Body>
    </MessageStart>

Comment: This is very difficult to read. Please put it in your question.

Comment: Updated the xml as suggested.

Comment: I have added a solution.